# UIViewConroller Slow to Load and Pauses OpenGL/Audio thread

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

I have an openGL/audio iOS application and several UIViewControllers that are presented (popovers or modal views) when a button is pressed. When the controllers are created/shown they pause the main openGL/audio thread for .5-1 second while opening.

To combat this, I tried allocating all the view controllers (there's not that many) when the application loads - rather than each time they're used. However, even though they're allocated/created early on, the first time they're shown they still are slow to appear and pause the main thread. After the first time each one is loaded, the next times it is quick and does not pause anything.

Is there a way to preload the UIViewControllers? It seems that allocating from nib is not the slow down (since that occurs when the app starts) and therefore it's something with presenting the view. Each UIViewController UIView only has 4-5 sliders and 2-3 buttons. There really isn't that much where it should take time to load.

Is there a way to thread this somehow to avoid the lag? From what I understand UIKit elements can only run in the main thread.

Comment: Activity on the main thread doesn't have the capacity to pause other threads. When you say "OpenGL/Audio thread" are you sure you aren't actually updating those on the main thread, in the normal runloop?

Comment: Yeah, it may be the case that they're updated from the main thread in the normal runloop. I'm curious how to move the openGL ES aspect to its own thread.